# How to create query-based reports using user input?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a report that pulls all transactions on a given day, and while I'm able to generate a static report (choosing an account at random by me and pulling all transactions for an arbitrary date), I need to be able to allow for user input so the user can select the date for which they'd like to see all transactions. How would I go about doing this?

See example table below...

```
TRANSACTIONS

ID|DATE       |STORE_ID |ACCT_ID
--+-----------+---------+---------
 1| 02/07/2017|      113|    1005
 2| 02/01/2017|      557|    1003
 3| 02/04/2017|      224|    1000
 4| 02/07/2017|      678|    1005
 5| 02/09/2017|      579|    1003
 6| 02/11/2017|      678|    1000
 7| 02/07/2017|      900|    1005
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what Forms are for. Basically, a form has one or more "controls" that a user uses to specify various criteria. Then they click a button (another kind of control) which opens a report which is based on a query that references those form controls, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM tblTransactions 
WHERE ACCT_ID = Forms!MyForm!ctrlAccountID AND
[DATE] < Forms!MyForm!ctrlDate;
```

You can layout the form and the report however you'd like. Access has a Form Wizard that can help you with the layout of the form, and creating a button only requires adding that control and then double clicking the button to open the VBA window, where you'd add code like:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "myReport", acViewReport
```

I have created an [imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vph07.jpg) showing the process. Also, here is [my example Access file](http://www.filedropper.com/so-access1).

Comment: Thanks for that example, Will. I am wondering, instead of having the query for the report referencing the form (feels wrong to have a hard dependency like that), is there a pattern for passing in the account ID and date values as parameters?

Comment: Lookup query parameters you will find a lot  on it. You can do that as well, but if your query will only be used by this form then Will's answer looks just fine..

Comment: Absolutely, you could make the query for the report have unspecified parameters that the report will ask you for when you open it. For example, if the record source of the report is "SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE ACCT_ID=[Please enter your account ID]", you'll get a prompt when the report opens asking you for the account ID. You can do the same for the date. However, you have less control over user input, what the prompt looks like, etc.